# I can't make new linked tables between my Access front-end and MS-SQL backend

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access

I have split my database, and everything is working as it should. However, I have just created a new table in my database using SQL 2014 Management (MSS) Studio. Now, I am trying to sync it with my Access front-end using the "External Data" tutorial. The problem is that I can't find my database file. For example, in MSS, I get the file path:

[image]

But when I try to select it, it doesn't show up:

[image]

I assume that I am missing something, right? I would greatly appreciate the community's feedback. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't link to a database by navigating to the .mdf file. In fact the .mdf file should not be accessible off the server at all. And it certainly should not be accessible from your end users.

Instead you should be navigating to the server where your database is running. Like `\\YourServerName\YourSqlServerInstanceName`

The directory you are looking in is searching for .dsn files which say *how* to connect to a server. Use the `New...` button to create a new Sql Server DSN and follow the prompts form there.